# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes after last update to kernel 5.4.0-56

Tags: 20.04, kernel, updates

Today the kernel on Ubuntu 20.04 was updated to 5.4.0-56-generic and my computer works slowly and freezes. On 5.4.0-54-generic it works without problems. How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here...I managed to get out of it using Ctrl+Alt+Backspace then login followed by grub customizer and then selected an older kernel "5.4.0-54-Generic" in my case as default.

Comment: I updated Ubuntu to 20.10 and works fine on kernel 5.8